# Recover from git reset --hard HEAD

Tags: git, reset

I need help, I had files that were not added to the repo yet.
I did

```
 git add this.php
 git add file.php
```

then I decided I wanted to unstage them so I did

```
 git reset --hard HEAD
```

Now these files are gone. How can I recover these files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily for you, you added those file to the index before nuking them from your working copy. In this case they are already contained in Git's object database. (First create a backup, just in case you mess something up).

Run `git fsck` (maybe with `--full` flag) and look out for "dangling blobs". Then use `git show $hash` to display the contents of the blobs. If you find your files (there might be several similar versions), use `git show $hash > path/to/file` to write them to disk again.

Comment: Wow, what a relief. This works. I was using fsck without --full so the blobs were not showing up for those files. I need to learn

Answer (score 0):

You cannot recover the files after a hard reset without having committed them.

You should have rather done a soft/mixed reset, which will just unstage the files. You can see the same suggestion from git when you do a `git status` after staging the files.

Comment: OP added them before calling `reset --hard` so they are already part of Git's object database and can be recovered with `git fsck`. If he hadn't, then the files would be lost forever.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Learnt it now! :-)